# How to load autocomplete data with scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have created jquery auto completed search . i have to load more than 1000 of records inside my autocomplete dropdown . I want to make it change to scroll 10 records at first time once user scroll down next record will appear , Please advice me on this /

Comment: Take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight

Comment: @j809: i have put max height . but what i want is to make load only 10 records first. once the scrolling down only start loading other records. kind of pagination

Comment: Did you try out as in my answer? Worked?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that I won't be able to write the entire code for you, as SO is not a place where you get people working for your code.

But, I will surely show you some steps by which you will be able to achieve it.

1. Load/store all the entries returned by your `PHP` in a variable.
2. Then, you will need to bind the event for which the autocomplete dropdown must refresh to load next 10 entries. For example, it may be `Down` arrow `keydown` event.
3. This bound event must check if the focused element is the 10th entry. Maintain a variable to store the index of focused element, which would change on `Up` or `Down` arrow `keydown`.
4. Then, if your focused element is 10th element and user would press a `Down` key, then you should fire an autocomplete `search` event.

**JS**

```
var items[] = ... //your autocomplete items cached
var focused = 1;  //maintain variable to store focused element
$(input).bind( "keydown", function( event ) { //bind keydown event
    if ( event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN ) {
        ++focused;
        if(focused==10){
            $(input).autocomplete("option","source",//items from 1-10, 11-20,... changing for each page);
            $(input).autocomplete("search",searchParam);//searchParam is input content, you can filter it to get last typed word
            focused=1; //Reset focused element to first
        }
    }
    else if ( event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.UP ) {
        --focused;
    }
});
```

This is just a **small sample just to show**. You will need to **make lot of changes** to it and add much more to get what you want.